# Why can't I reference an item in a JSON array without using ng-repeat?

Tags: json, angularjs

This is probably stupidly basic, but I can't seem to find a straight answer on Google.

I am generating a JSON array from a MySQL database using a GET call to a PHP script:

```
widgetshopControllers.controller('phpTestCtrl',function($scope,$http,$routeParams){
        $http.get('php/widgets.php?widget_id=' + $routeParams.widgetId).success(function(response){
            $scope.widgets = response
        })
        .error(function (err){
            console.error(err)
        })
    })
```

This gives me a standard JSON array in `response`, and so AFAIC `$scope.widgets` contains that array, e.g.:

```
[{"name":"Blue Widget","description":"A really nice blue widget","size":"large"}]
```

In my view, why can't I simply display, for example, the `name` using:

```
<h2>{{widgets.name}}</h2>
```

? If I use `ng-repeat`, like `<h2 ng-repeat = "widget in widgets">{{widget.name}}</h2>` it works fine, but it seems wrong to use `ng-repeat` without actually repeating anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `widgets` is an array, you need to use the index of the item you want to display:

```
<h2>{{widgets[0].name}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's an array.  You either need to do `{{widgets[0].name}}` or find some way to set the currently selected widget to the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat allows you to iterate over an array. Going over each item one by one and interpolating the value. Without an ng-repeat {{widgets.name}} doesn't know which value to interpolate.

So without iterating over each item, with the help of ng-repeat, you'll need to define which value in the array you want it to interpolate. `{{widgets[0].name}}` or `{{widgets[1].name}}`